# Copying data and storing it for manual paste in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to activate a range and COPY it, but not paste it (aka don't set the values).

I want to do this because I want a "copy" button that selects range a3:e3, then the user can manually paste it into an Excel sheet.

I tried connecting right to excel, but it wasn't worth the headache. I'm just trying to save the user the step of highlighting the range and clicking CTRL C.

Is this possible in Apps Script? this is the code I thought might work

```
function copyToFile() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet and select the range to copy
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Label Prep");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:E3");
  
  // Get the data from the range
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  // Create a string from the data
  var dataString = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataString += data[i].join("\t") + "\n";
  }
  
  // Create a content object and download it as a text file
  var content = ContentService.createTextOutput(dataString);
  content.downloadAsFile("data.txt");
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between having an array of data in a variable and having it in a clipboard

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `I'm just trying to save the user the step of highlighting the range and clicking CTRL C.` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue and your goal?

Comment: `function copyToFile()`: _this is the code I thought might work_ I'm confused, Anthony. If you thought this might work, then what happens when you run it?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion -- I'm essentially looking to use apps script to copy this range to my clipboard, so that I can paste it elsewhere. Right now, nothing is happening when I run the code